# @Published property not triggering anything

Tags: swift, swift5

I have this protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol:ObservableObject {
  var codeDetected:CodeDetected { get set }
  var codeDetectedPublished: Published<CodeDetected> { get }
  var codeDetectedPublisher: Published<CodeDetected>.Publisher { get }
}
```

This is CodeDetected

```
class CodeDetected:ObservableObject {
  var title: String
  var value:String

  init(title:String = "", value:String = ""){
    self.title = title
    self.value = value
  }
}
```

later on a class...

```
class MyModel: MyProtocol {

  @Published var codeDetected:CodeDetected = CodeDetected()
  var codeDetectedPublished: Published<CodeDetected> { _codeDetected}
  var codeDetectedPublisher: Published<CodeDetected>.Publisher { $codeDetected }
}
```

The problem is that changing `codeDetected` on this class, does not trigger anything on the structs observing it.

Later on the implementation

```
struct MyView: View {
  @ObservedObject let myModel = MyModel()
```

I am setting new values for it like

```
codeDetected = newCodeDetected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Observing you model

```
@StateObject var myModel = MyModel()
```

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we are going in pieces here.

You aren't observing `title` and `value` either. put an `@Published` on them and then observe them in their own `View`

```
protocol MyProtocol:ObservableObject {
    var codeDetected:CodeDetected { get set }
    //var codeDetectedPublished: Published<CodeDetected> { get }
    //var codeDetectedPublisher: Published<CodeDetected>.Publisher { get }
}

class CodeDetected:ObservableObject {
    @Published var title: String
    @Published var value:String
    
    init(title:String = "init", value:String = "init"){
        self.title = title
        self.value = value
    }
}
class MyModel: MyProtocol {
    
    @Published var codeDetected:CodeDetected = CodeDetected()
    //var codeDetectedPublished: Published<CodeDetected> { _codeDetected}
    //var codeDetectedPublisher: Published<CodeDetected>.Publisher { $codeDetected }
}
struct CodeDetectedView: View {
    @StateObject var myModel = MyModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Can't see updates here unless you ask for them/tell the parent model there are changes
            Text(myModel.codeDetected.title)
            .onReceive(myModel.codeDetected.$title, perform: { _ in
                myModel.objectWillChange.send()
            })
            Text(myModel.codeDetected.value)
                .onReceive(myModel.codeDetected.$value, perform: { _ in
                    myModel.objectWillChange.send()
                })
            CodeDetectedSubView(codeDetected: myModel.codeDetected)
        }
    }
}
struct CodeDetectedSubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var codeDetected: CodeDetected
    var body: some View {
        //Can see here
        Text(codeDetected.title)
        Text(codeDetected.value)
        TextField("title", text: $codeDetected.title)
        TextField("value", text: $codeDetected.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@ObservedObject` instead of `@StateObject`? Sorry, I have it as `@ObservedObject` on my code. Failed to add it to the question. Sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Not when you are initializing in the same `View` you can but [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) recommends the "more stable" `StateObject` for this. `ObservedObject` is for when the object comes from another `View` like a `ForEach` of CoreData Objects that use a `NavigationLink` where the object is observed on its own.

Comment: `title` and `value` need wrappers and observation too.

Comment: I put up some code for you. I think your biggest thing is that you are chaining `ObservableObjects` SwiftUI can't look that far. But you can force it to refresh by observing the items.