# update View when view model's, publish object's, property is updated

Tags: swiftui, combine

How to update view, when view models publish var's (user's) , name property is updated. I do know why its happening but what is the best way to update the view in this case.

```
class User {
    var id  = "123"
    @Published  var name = "jhon"
}
```

---

```
 class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var user : User = User()
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
     @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel() 
    
    var body: some View  {
        userNameView 
    }

    var userNameView: some View  {
        Text(viewModel.user.name)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                viewModel.user.name += "update"
                print( viewModel.user.name)
            }
    }
}
```

so one way i do it, is by using onReceive like this,

```
var body: some View  {

         userNameView
             .onReceive(viewModel.user.$name){ output in

                    let tmp = viewModel.user
                           viewModel.user = tmp
                    print("onTapGesture",output)

          }
}
```

but it is not a good approach it will update all view using users properties.
should i make a @state var for the name?
or should i just make a ObservedObject for user as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Published property not triggering anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259182/published-property-not-triggering-anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you class conform to `ObservableObject`

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    var id  = "123"
    @Published  var name = "jhon"
}
```

But he catch with that is that you have to observe it directly you can't chain it in a `ViewModel`

Use `@ObservedObject var user: User` in a `View`

Comment: yes i did tried the chaining but it does not work. so i should set user in the init of the view or in the didAppear? what is the best way to go about it. Thanks for the answer highly appreciated.

Comment: The `user` should come from a parent `View` so in the `init`. Don't find it in the `init` the parent has to pass it to the `init`.

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259182/published-property-not-triggering-anything/66261277#66261277) I wrote a pretty detailed answer for this situation

Comment: I knew we can use the observed object, but was thinking is there any other simpler way to go about it. thanks for the help.

Comment: Look t the question I posted there is a way to do it the way you were doing it but you have to listen for changes using `onReceive` and forcing a `ViewModel` update.

Comment: yes you are doing the same as mine onReceive. only difference is that you are calling objectWillChange.send() and i am just updating the user by its own value, to let view know that user updated.

Answer (score -1):

You should use struct:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct User {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

---

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var user : User = User(id: "123", name: "Mike")
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View  {
        userNameView
    }

    var userNameView: some View  {
        
        Text(viewModel.user.name)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                viewModel.user.name += " update"
                print( viewModel.user.name)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: can not use struct user is a realm object.